# NSURLCache not storing cached data in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, nsurlcache

Below given code works in iOS 6 but it does not work on iOS 7.

```
NSCachedURLResponse cachedURLResponse = [[NSCachedURLResponse alloc] initWithResponse:response data:data userInfo:nil storagePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] storeCachedResponse:cachedURLResponse forRequest:request];
NSLog(@"Cached response is %@", [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] cachedResponseForRequest:request]);
```

In iOS 6 I am getting the cached response data but in iOS 7 it returns null. 
I have set the NSURLCache object in App delegate using:

```
NSURLCache *urlCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:2 * 1024 * 1024
                                                     diskCapacity:2 * 1024 * 1024
                                                         diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:urlCache];
```

What is the reason of caching not working in iOS 7?

Comment: Did you try clearing caches on your machine and then try your code??

Comment: yup, tried clearing caches. Still does not work in iOS7

Comment: Subclass NSURLCache and you will be able to see just about everything that is going on here.

Comment: Try the same code in iOS 7.1 (XCode 5.1_DP2). They have resolved some issue in 7.0.4. Not sure which issue.

Comment: Ran the code in the latest XCode version, still not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing a POST method and setting the http_body with the required NSData.
In iOS 6, the response was being cached but this was not working in iOS 7.

So, now instead of setting http_body, we are appending the param in the url and making a request and caching is working now.

Answer (score 1):

Caching mechanism relies on HTTP headers. Check returned HTTP headers if caching is allowed in first place. You may do it with web proxies like 'Charles'.